# strictly monotonic increasing continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$. Let $a_0\in{[0,1]}$ define $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$. Prove convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Given is a strictly monotonic increasing continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$. Let $a_0\in{[0,1]}$ define $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ for $n=0,1,2,...$. Prove that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ converges. In the previous exercise I've proven that there exists a $c\in{[0,1]}$ such that $f(c)=c$.

There are three cases,

**case 1** $f(a_0)=a_0$, in this case $a_n=a_{n+1}$ for all $n=0,1,2,...$ and proving the sequence is convergent is simple.

**case 2** $f(a_0)>a_0$ so $a_1>a_0$. Because $f$ is strictly monotonic increasing it holds that, if $a_{n+1}>a_n$ then $f(a_{n+1})>f(a_n)$ and $a_{n+2}>a_{n+1}$. So $a_0<a_1<a_2<...$. Because $f$ is bounded $a_n$ is also bounded. It seems because $a_0<a_1<a_2<...$ and $a_n<1$ for all $n=0,1,2,...$ I should be able to prove that $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ is converging. It seems logical to me that it converges to $c=f(c)$ but I don't know how to prove that.

**case 3** $f(a_0)<a_0$ should be similair to case 2

Comment: Monotone and bounded sequences always converge, if you can use that theorem. Then you are already finished.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't

Comment: Then here's the simple proof: A monotonically increasing (the theorem holds even without it being strict) and bounded sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to its supremum $a$ with $a\neq -\infty$ due to the sequence being nonempty and $a\neq\infty$ due to its boundness. Take $\varepsilon>0$, then there exists a $N\in\mathbb{N}$, so that $a-\varepsilon<a_N\leq a$, which implies that for all $n>N$, we have $a-\varepsilon<a_N\leq a_n\leq a$, and therefore $a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}a$.

Comment: Thank you Samuel

Comment: @gordon: if $a_1=f(a_0)<a_1$, then by induction $a_{n+1}<f(a_n)$: suppose $a_{n-1}<a_n$. Then $a_n=f(a_{n-1})<f(a_n)=a_{n+1}$. Your. sequence $(a_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is monotone decreasing and bounded.

Comment: What is the function of the word "monotonic" in the phrase "strictly monotonic increasing"?

Comment: Remark that it does not especially converges to $c$ as you said. All you know is that it converges to a fixed point of $f$, but $c$ is maybe not the only one.